# How to not involve the access path of this pointer,use a non-const member function inside a const member function?

Tags: c++

I read while browsing on the cppreference website that within a member function with the `const` qualifier, it is possible to call a member function without the `const` qualifier.

[member functions with cv-qualifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions)

> (A member function without `const` qualifier may still be called if `const_cast` is applied or through an access path that does not involve `this`.)

I can understand through `const_cast` keyword bypassing, but I can't understand the meaning of "through an access path that does not involve `this`". What do I need to do to successfully bypass it?

Here is the relevant code:

```cpp
struct type
{
   int i = 0;

   void test()
   {
      std::cout << "\ntest()\n" << std::endl;
   }

   void f1(int v) const
   {
      //this->i = v;//Error.
      const_cast<type*>(this)->i = v;
      const_cast<type*>(this)->test();
   }

   void f2(int v) const
   {
      //test();//The member function is still implicitly called through the "this" pointer, so an error will still be reported.
      //this->test();//Error.
      //type::test();//Error.
      
      //what should I do?
   }
};

int main()
{
   int i = 0;
   const int& rci = i;
   const_cast<int&>(rci) = 5;
   std::cout << "i = " << i << '\n';//print:i = 5.

   type t;
   t.f1(10);
   std::cout << "t.i = " << t.i << '\n';//print:t.i = 10.

   const type ct1;
   ct1.f1(20);
   std::cout << "ct.i = " << ct1.i << '\n';//print:ct1.i = 20.

   const type ct2;
   ct2.f2(30);
}
```

Comment: I think they mean that you can call a non-`const` member function from another instance of the class. Something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/fPjbzsT9E) where `incrementAndPrintAnother` is a `const` member function that invokes the non-`const` member function `incrementAndPrint`, but on behalf of another object instance.

Comment: @Nathan Pierson: I understand, this method does not violate the definition it says, thank you.